# Can't get Height of Textarea

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I want to know the height of my  but my code does not work and gives erro Cannot read property 'height' of undefined

HTML

```
 <textarea #box  (click)='onClick($event)'></textarea>
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('box') box:ElementRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>;
  onClick(event){
    console.log(this.box.style.height)
  }
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

How can I resolve this I think have defined box as HTMLTextAreaElement then why is it saying undefined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try using `nativeElement` instead.

```
import { Component, ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('box') box:ElementRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>;
  onClick(event){
    console.log(this.box.nativeElement.style.height)
  }
  name = 'Angular';
}
```